# AggregatedView - Renam models on model structure panel

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm implementing Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView, and it's working great. The only issue I'm having is renaming modelStructurePanel node labels. The parent nodes get their names based on the filename of the file uploaded to the OSS bucket. I'd like to override this name with a custom one.

I've tried two approaches:

## 1 - Renaming nodes

```js
const model = this.aggregatedView.getModel(viewable[0]);
const it = model.getInstanceTree();
```

**Unfortunately, there is no method like setNodeName**

## 2 - Extending the default class and overriding getNodeLabel:

```js
class CustomModelStructurePanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ModelStructurePanel {
  getNodeLabel(node) {
    return 'custom node name';
  }
}

const modelStructureExtension = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');
modelStructureExtension.setModelStructurePanel(new CustomModelStructurePanel(viewer.container, 'myPanel', 'My Structure Panel'));
```

In this case, the label names remain the same as before, and the panel becomes strange.

Any ideas on how to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can override the root node name like below by passing `CustomLoadOptions` for the room model, when using the AggregatedView class.

```js
let roomUrn = 'dXJuOmF...';

const options3d = {
  getCustomLoadOptions: (bubble) => {
    let loadOptions = null
    if (bubble.getDocument().myData.urn == roomUrn)
        loadOptions = { modelNameOverride: 'Rooms Only' };

    return loadOptions;
  }
};

view.init( viewerDiv, options3d );
```